# Need help using Nokigiri when trying to retrieve a tags from the NYT cooking website

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

```
def fetch_recipe_urls
  base_url = 'https://cooking.nytimes.com'
  easy_recipe_url = 'https://cooking.nytimes.com/search?q=easy'
  easy_searchpage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(easy_recipe_url).read)
  recipes = easy_searchpage.search('.card.recipe-card')
  array = recipes.map do |recipe|
    uri = URI.parse(recipe.attributes["data-url"].value)
    uri.scheme = "http"
    uri.host = "cooking.nytimes.com"
    uri.query = "easy"
    uri.to_s
  end

end
```

I am trying to scrape the urls in this html attached. However it is saying that there are is a undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass. I have provided a link to the website below.

https://cooking.nytimes.com/search?q=easy

Comment: Jonathan, remember to upvote people that help you, and approve their answers if they solved your issue.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"
 is your friend. Your code is missing the minimum required input data (HTML) necessary to demonstrate the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to just

```
 array = recipes.map {|recipe| {recipe.name => recipe.attributes('data-url')&.value} }
```

You will notice some of the nodes selected are not 'articles' but rather sections and do not have a data-url attribute (e.g. `nil`) which is your current issue.

If you would still like to use css use `"article.card.recipe-card"` as your selector to ensure you are only selecting the article tags (which all have a 'data-url' attribute).

However, I generally prefer xpath over css selectors as I feel they are more functional and offer better granularity.

That being the case you can achieve your goal as follows

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
base_url = 'https://cooking.nytimes.com'
easy_recipe_url = 'https://cooking.nytimes.com/search?q=easy'
easy_searchpage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(easy_recipe_url))
recipes = easy_searchpage.search('//article[@class="card recipe-card"]/@data-url')
array = recipes.map do |recipe|
  uri = URI.parse(recipe.text)
  uri.scheme = "http"
  uri.host = "cooking.nytimes.com"
  uri.query = "easy"
  uri.to_s
end
```

The XPath will select all the article tags (`//article`) with a class of "card recipe-card" (`[@class="card recipe-card"]`) and return just the data-url attribute (`/@data-url`). This allows you to iterate over just the data-url attributes rather than all the nodes returned with your current selector.

Comment: Thank you so much- would it be possible to show me an example of what is not an article but a 'section'. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanPein I am not 100% sure what you mean. If you look at the page source you will see 3 of these section tags with  id="search-paid-post-tablet-ad", id="search-paid-post-mobile-landscape-ad", id="search-paid-post-mobile-ad". All of these have the classes "card recipe-card".